# Windows Service Multi Threading issue Threads are not working properly

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asp.net-core, windows-services

I am working on a windows service where we are connecting devices to device reader.

1. Service Takes all Offline Devices
2. Service Creates a thread list and for every device it creates one thread and Sleep for 1 second. Then create thread for another device and  add it to the list. For example if there are 10 devices and 7 are online it will create 7 threads with the gap of 1 second.
3. After that Thread will Sleep for 5 mins and then resume again and recheck the offline devices and add them to thread if any new device comes online.

```
 private static async void StartDeviceConnections()
        {
            Thread th = Thread.CurrentThread;
            th.Name = "MainThread";
            var threads = new List<Thread>();
            var onlyOffline = false;
            setupDeviceTimer();
            setupSyncLogsTimer();
            nextCycle:
            try
            {
                var objDevice = new DeviceService();
                objDevice.UpdateDeviceStatus(0, DeviceStatuses.Offline, "updateAll");
                var devices = new DeviceService().GetOfflineIRISDevices();
                if (devices != null && devices.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var device in devices)
                    {
                        Thread childThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate () { DeviceSyncManager(device); }));
                        childThread.Start();
                        childThread.Name = device.ipAddress;
                        threads.Add(childThread);
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
            // wait for the next cycle
            Thread.Sleep(MinutesToCheckDeviceStatusAgain * 60 * 1000);
            onlyOffline = true;
             goto nextCycle;
        }
```

But it seems like it is not working fine when i try to run service I get this error.

> Windows could not start the service on Local computer. Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control in the timely fashion

Only way this code is running is by commenting line goto statement.
but in that way it will not recheck the online devices and live status cannont be maintained.

I have tried to change sleep value as well.
Time is really short and i couldnt try much.
I have another idea to revamp the code but it will take time.

Comment: Whenever you feel the need to run `Thread.Sleep`, consider if you should be using a timer instead. The current code will block the thread and prevent the service from responding to messages from windows, so windows will think it has hanged.

Comment: _"Threads are not working properly"_ - In most cases, it will be rather an error or misuse on your side. Bugs do happen but you should really make sure you have indisputable proof before making such a claim.

Comment: Oh and don't use `goto`. Just forget it is supported. An empty catch block is also a huge no-go. At least log errors.

Comment: You may want to consider kicking off a CPU-Bound long running Task and using [PeriodicTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer?view=net-8.0).

Comment: `async void` && not an event Handler == red flag.

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because your StartDeviceConnections never finishes.
If you need this code to run continuously, you could do it in another thread.
Something like this:

```
    private static void StartDeviceConnections()
    {
        new Thread(() => {
          //the code that is currently in the StartDeviceConnections
    }).Start();
}
```

Comment: I'd provide something like a CancellationToken as stopping signal to have a possibility to shutdown the thread gracefully. OP talked about this being a Windows Service, so a stopping token may already be provided by the framework.